# If statement not working properly

Tags: php, android, if-statement

I'm trying to fix a login function to my app using HTTP POST's. I'm sending from a username and a password field.

I managed it to work at first, now when I've added a function for creating a sharedpreference in the app. The if statement who reads the result does not seem to work.

```
super.onPostExecute(result);
if(result.equals("yes")){
    loggedIn();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

*If* it reads "yes" from the PHP response is will run another function. But that never happens, what happens is that it reads the **ELSE** instead. To find out whats wrong I made a Toast of what the PHP responds, and it responds "yes". Why doesn't it work?
Any clue?

Comment: Try `if(result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not exactly sure about your problem but as the toast is showing yes then there are some possibilities

1. case mismatch. In this case use `equalIgnoreCases` method
2. extra space in the response. in this case use `contains` or `indexof` to be sure

after combining both as Rajesh said in comment

you can use

`result = result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yes");`

Comment: btw i am just curious.. what was your problem?? :D .. I just guessed it

Comment: `if (result.contains(checker))` did the trick, I made "checker" a string aswell. Thanks! @StinePike

Comment: The if should run a function if the PHP response was "yes". But "if" didn't want to and let "else" send a toast to show me how the response looked like..and the response was "yes". So..I don't know how it got like this because I've used `if(result.equals("yes"))` before